# OO Black Jack Game - computing hand values

Tags: python

Running the program will cause an error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

The problem is with the line `value += values.get(card.get_rank)`

I think there may be a problem with the `get_rank` method?  Does it not return an integer?

```
ranks = ('A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K')
values = {'A':1,'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,'9':9,'10':10,'J':10,'Q':10,'K':10}
suits = ('Diamonds','Hearts','Clubs','Diamonds')
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
    def __str__(self, suit, rank):
        print (self.rank + 'of' + self.rank)
    def get_rank(self):
        return self.rank
class Hand:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = []
    def __str__(self):
        hand = ''
        for card in self.hand:
            hand = hand + str(card)
        return hand
    def get_value(self):
        value = 0
        aces = 0
        for card in self.hand:
            if card.get_rank == 'A':
                aces += 1
            value += values.get(card.get_rank)

            if (aces>0) and (value + 10 <= 21):
                value += 10
        return value
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `values`?

Comment: values is adictionary, that I initialized in the beginning.  I'll edit my post above and put it in.  sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`values.get(card.get_rank)` tries to use the *instance method* as the key for the dictionary. This is not a valid key in the dictionary, so `dict.get()` returns the default `None`.

Instead you want to *call* the method, and use the `return` value as the key:

```
value += values.get(card.get_rank())
```

or, as trivial getters and setters are unpythonic, just access the attribute directly:

```
value += values.get(card.rank)
```

Note that you can also pass a default to `dict.get()` to ensure you always get a sensible return value:

```
value += values.get(card.rank, 0)
```

Now if there is no value for that card rank in `values`, its value is assumed to be zero.

---

Also, it's not clear where `values` is coming from. I would suggest you make it a *class attribute*:

```
class Hand:

    VALUES = {...}

    ...

    def get_value(self):
        ...
            value += self.VALUES.get(card.rank, 0)
             ...
```

Or an explicit argument to `get_value`:

```
class Hand:

    ...

    def get_value(self, values):
        ...
            value += self.values.get(card.rank, 0)
            ...
```

Comment: If you make the ranks `2`-`10` actual integers, you can put only the face cards `'A'`, `'J'`, `'Q'`, `'K'` in `values` and use `values.get(card.rank, card.rank)`. Also, note you have an error in `Card.__str__`.

Comment: thanks for point out the error in Card.__str__.  My hand.__str__ doesn't work.  Does anyone know why?
<code>
    def __str__(self):
        hand = ''
        for card in self.hand:
            hand = hand + str(card)
        return hand <code>

Comment: It's hard to read code in comments, but I'd recommend `return ", ".join(map(str, self.hand))`

Comment: I edited it into my original post, if you would kindly look at it.  I was just banned from asking more questions =(  .  So the only thing I can do now is comment and edit.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You should learn from getting banned - ask better questions! What does *"doesn't work"* mean? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)? Include a [minimal example](http://sscce.org) to demonstrate the problem and describe it precisely. While you're at it, just look at `suits`.

Comment: I tried calling player.__str__() in another function, and I get this error message

The error message I get is :TypeError: __str__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'suit' and 'rank'.  

Thank you for pointing out the mistake in suits

Comment: `__str__` should only have one argument; `self`.

Comment: That did the trick for me.  I'm still very new to OOP.  Thanks so much for your patience and help!  I really appreciate it.